# Android studio how to access server files?

Tags: sql-server, android-studio

I want to make an app as my final project for my teacher. I will have images of homework assignments and the date of homework assigned in text format in the server. And I want to make an app where it will access it and put it in an activity.

So I need to know what kind of server do I need, if I could just use google drive somehow or not?

Comment: did you resolve this question?

Answer (score 0):

Save it as **JSON**, you save the images on your database and call it in your JSON.

But for what you intend to do I think FireBase will work just file because it is free for small projects like this.